# How to get string match starting position in str.contains() on polars?

Tags: python

I know I can use str.contains() to check if a string is contained in a column, like:

```
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame({"a": ["my name is Bob","my little pony, my little pony"]})
(df.with_columns(bbb = pl.col('a').str.slice(1,10000).str.contains(pl.col('a').str.slice(0,10), literal=True)
                  )
 )
```

What i'd like is the exact starting position of the match and not just a boolean, like in:

```
import re
x = re.search(r"pony","my little pony")
print(x.start(),x.end())
```

How can I do that?

Comment: can't you use `apply` and use a custom function using the str method `find` to get a column with the position of the substring ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Series.str.find()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/series/api/polars.Series.str.find.html) method:

```py
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame({"a": ["my name is Bob","my little pony, my little pony"]})
df.with_columns(
    bbb=pl.col('a').str.slice(1,10000).str.find(
            pl.col('a').str.slice(0,10), literal=True)
        )
 )
```